# Kendo grid, change text on edit button

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that looks a bit like this (code edited for clarity):

```
    var gridList = $('##listBo').kendoGrid({

        ...

        columns: [
            ...
            {
                command: "edit"
                , title: 'Edit' // Need to make this text conditional
                , width: 91
            }
        ]

        ...

        , editable: {
                mode: "popup"
                , template: $("##addEditPopup").html()
                , window: {
                open: loadJSOnWindowLaunch 
                , title: "Reservation request"
            }
            }
        , dataBound: function(e) {
            dataBoundFunction();
        }

    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

I need to make the button say 'Edit' in some circumstances and 'View' in others, based on values in the datasource.

How do I best do this?

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach to deal with this situation is to make a custom command column and then using template option you can render the column button according to your condition.

Try like this :

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    toolbar: ["create"],
                    columns: [
                        { field:"ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                        { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                        { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px" },
                        { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px" },
                        { template: comandTemplate }],
                    editable: "popup"
                });
            });
            // render command column button based on condition
            function comandTemplate(model){
                // here i use Discontinued attribute to data model to show
                // view detail button or edit button
                if(model.Discontinued==0)
                {
                    return '<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    return '<a class="k-button k-button-icontext" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewDetailsAction()">View Details</a>';
                }
            }
            // Custom action if view detail button click
            function viewDetailsAction()
            {
                alert("Your custom action for view detail");
            }
```

Here is a working sample http://dojo.telerik.com/AdAKO

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi. I tried something broadly similar before I asked the question here. The problem I had is that, if you look in my original code, when the 'Edit' button is pressed, I need all the things that are in the 'editable' node to execute (ie, launch a popup, run a JS function, etc). How can I use your solution and still get those things to run?

Comment: Hi Michael, If you check the demo i have created you can see the edit popup work very well. And if you want execute any function on event you can as usual. Let me know what function you want to execute on what event.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add custom column in columns like this

```
{ 
   template: "# if (property == true) { # <a class="k-button k-grid-edit" 
   href="#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a> # } else { #
   <a class="k-button"><span onClick="callFunction()"
   </span>View</a> # } #", width: "150px"
}
```

- where "property" is a field which will be use as condition field to display different buttons.

Hope, This will work for you. (ThumbsUp)